# If statement is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I said I had fixed the issues I was having in a previous post, but it turns out I did not. My site, https://coolkids.gq, uses some JavaScript code to change the page CSS only if iOS is used. However, the `if() {}` part of the code does not seem to work. I've tried multiple variations, including using double equals, using "true", 'true', true and TRUE as what _iOSDevice should equal and putting $ in front of _iOSDevice. Here's my current JS code:

```
var _iOSDevice = !!navigator.platform.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad/);

if (_iOSDevice === "true") {
    document.html.style.height = "400%";
    document.html.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.maincode.style.min-height = "calc(1000% + 50px)";
}
```

How could I fix it to function properly?

Comment: `.match()` will return an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value), so `_iOSDevice` will always be `true`. Consider using [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead

Comment: It should definitely be `if (_iOSDevice === true)` + the above ^^.

Comment: @goto1 - !! sets the value to a boolean - so testing against "true" is totally redundant. Like saying if(true === true) or if(false === true) - it is pointless because the value is already a boolean.

Comment: _correction to my statement above_: `.match()` can return null if no matches are found, so changing `TRUE` to `true` is most likely all you need to do. But I still think it is better/easier to use `.test()` rather than `.match()` for this

Comment: @NickParsons !! makes the value a boolean - !!null = false

Comment: @Fraser yeah, and !!<array> will make it `true`, so if a match is found and an array is returned then it'll be `true`, otherwise `false`, hence all that probably needs to be changed is `_iOSDevice === true` ...

Comment: @NickParsons - exactly using !! will make the return of match into a boolean (!! makes *anything* into a boolean) - so the test simply needs to be if(_iOSDevice)

Comment: @Fraser yep, I agree with that :)

Comment: You can use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of `match` if you just want a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `if(_iOSDevice === TRUE)` with `if(_iOSDevice)`. `true` should be lowercased, moreover in your case it's unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

test() method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false. So in this case, we are checking if the navigator.userAgent matches iPad, iPhone or iPod.

```
var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if (isIOS) {
  document.html.style.height = "400%";
  document.html.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.maincode.style.min-height = "calc(1000% + 50px)";
} else {
  console.log('This is Not a IOS device');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var _iOSDevice = !!navigator.platform.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad/);

if(_iOSDevice) {
    document.html.style.height = "400%";
    document.html.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.maincode.style.min-height = "calc(1000% + 50px)";
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. === is for value AND type comparing

Comment: If you remove that `!!` and put a `if(_iOSDevice).length > 0` the answer would be correct

Comment: That subtraction operator on the last line doesn’t do what you think it does.

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.

Comment: This won't work, plus I've tested it - it doesn't. Quentin is right.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score -4):

I think you missed single quotes or double quotes in:

```
var _IOSDevice = !!navigator.platform.match('/Phone|iPod|iPad/');
```

Comment: In JavaScript, the `/<expression>/` syntax is used for regular expressions, so the quotes are not needed, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression)